# Store templated argument into a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I want to store a templated argument into my namespace.

I have no idea how to do that. This is a simplification of my code:

```
namespace sdc {
    template<typename T_output> 
    T_output last_o[dim_output];

    template<typename T_input, typename T_output>
    void training(T_input in[], T_output o_a[], T_output o_b[]) { 
        sdc::last_o = o_a;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> error: "last_o" is not a function or static data member

How could I do such a thing?

Comment: `sdc::last_o` looks like a variable template (though it's probably not what you want)

Comment: ok I have edited it. Actually I use last_i and last_o but I haven't shown the correct error message

Comment: @pl-94: I'm unable to reproduce that error message with g++. I guess it's *possible*, but most likely the code isn't the code that produced the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the given invalid code

```
namespace sdc {
template<typename T_output> 
T_output last_o[dim_output];
template<typename T_input, typename T_output>
void training(T_input in[], T_output o_a[], T_output o_b[]) { 
sdc::last_o = o_a;
}
}
```

… you can use a simple Meyers' singleton with `std::vector`, like this:

```
#include <vector>

namespace sdc {
    using std::vector;

    template< class Type > 
    auto last()
        -> vector<Type>&
    {
        static vector<Type> the_last;
        return the_last;
    }

    template< class Input, class Output>
    void training( vector<Input>& in, Vector<Output> a, Vector<Output> b )
    {
        sdc::last<Output>() = a;
    }
}  // namespace sdc
```

Do note well that this maintains a separate `sdc::last()` for each type `Output`.

If you want a common history for all types you will have to specify in more detail how you intend to access it.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

---

As noted by @vsoftco [in commentary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241995/store-templated-argument-into-a-namespace/33242249#comment54287251_33242072) on his answer, you can avoid the singleton by using a C++14 templated variable, exactly as in the original code except using e.g. a `std::vector` instead of a raw array, since raw arrays are not assignable. But doing so is ungood as a general convention, for two reasons. First, there is the notorious [“static initialization order fiasco” pitfall](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) to trap you when you least expect it. And secondly, not all readers of the code will know that the syntax is now supported – and presently that includes that not all compilers will know it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the assignment

```
sdc::last_o = o_a;
```

You cannot assign to an array (`std:: last_o` is an array, and **arrays are not pointers**, they decay to pointers when passed by value as function arguments). Other than that the code should work, assuming `dim_output` is a constant expression.

And in any case, `sdc::last_o` is a variable template (introduced in C++14), so it should be `std::last_o<TYPE>` instead.

Comment: C++ doesn't have templated variables.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I thought it's somehow implicit this was C++14, since OP is using them.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed they were introduced. Thanks. It must be the least useful feature in modern C++, just adding complexity. Harumph. :)